Defender recognizes my scheduled task as malicious
I have a scheduled task that defender keeps recognizing as malicious, the task runs an unsigned executable daily.
Sometimes the task runs for a few days and then it is being recognized as malicious - note that the scheduled task itself is being flaged as malicious and the exe is quarantined as consequence.
The executable folder is excluded from defender scans.
Is there a way to prevent my task from being blocked?

You can either report the false positive to Microsoft or exclude the directory with the executable and script. Have you tried either of those solutions? Outside of those actions there isn’t any other way other than increasing the reputation of the file, specifically, signing the executable and script.

The folder that contains the exe is already excluded.
Does the low reputation of the exe cause the scheduled task to be flagged or is it the existence of the task by itself?
Regarding exe signing, If I will self sign the exe and add the certificate to the store, will it be enough?

Just using a software certificate is enough, but raising the reputation, involves several elements
